# Получить данные с биржи Huobi в формате JSON

Tags: python, json, websocket, byte

Подскажите по поводу подключения к бирже Huobi через вебсокет.
Делаю вот так:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json, time, csv, gzip

async def main():
    url = "wss://api-aws.huobi.pro/ws"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        print(await ws.recv())
        recv = await ws.recv()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Получаю результат в байтах.
Мне нужно подключиться к каналу с котировками, например, по направлению atomusdt. Я так понимаю, мне нужно сделать await ws.send() и отправить, к примеру, вот эти данные {"req": "market.atomusdt.depth.step0","id": "id10"}, но видимо что-то не так делаю. Возможно так как результат приходит в байтах, то и send нужно в байтах делать. Подскажите по вебсокету, что необходимо сделать, чтобы правильно получить данные с этой биржи в формате JSON?

Comment: попробуйте вот [этот пример](https://github.com/huobiapi/Futures-Python-demo/blob/master/websocket-python3.6-demo/websocket_example.py). Возможно нужно будет заменить `market_url = 'wss://api.huobi.pro/ws'`

Comment: ws.recv().json()